# How can I send my Apple Notes to text files?

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

I have viewed the similar question on AskDifferent and it hasn't been helpful.

I have about 2000 iPhone notes, synced to my iCloud account, so I can access them on my iPhone or my laptop. I want to send them all to text files, put them on an external drive, and review them later. The current iTunes doesn't seem to allow any manual syncing notes option - it was said that it used to be possible to sync the notes to Mail and then download as text files from there.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the question/answer you are referring to and also describe why it's not helpful?

Comment: There's an answer on [superuser](http://superuser.com/a/486206). Alternative, there are some 3rd party apps that can do this for you such as _Notes Exporter_ from Writeapps.  I haven't used either method so can't say how well they work.